# Proper Convention for Injecting D3 into AngualrJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I've seen directives that just use the global D3 object, I've also seen directives that inject the global D3 object by just returning it in a service, and I've seen directives that add the D3 script and return a promise that is resolved on script load providing the D3 object.

Using it in an injectable service seems to make the most sense (see example 1 and 2), but I'm not sure which way is better.  Example 2 would guarantee that D3 had been loaded before running any code on it, but it doesn't seem like anyone does this, plus it means you have to wrap your entire directive in the service otherwise `d3` and the created `svg` object are out of scope or possibly undefined (see example 2), but at least the compile's promise I believe would always resolve first, see example 3.

**Example 1: Service passing D3 global object**

```
.factory('D3Service', [,
    function () {

        // Declare locals or other D3.js
        // specific configurations here.

        return d3;
    }]);
```

**Example 2: Service adding D3 script to DOM and passing promise**

```
.factory('D3Service', ['$window', '$document', '$q', '$rootScope',
    function ($window, $document, $q, $rootScope) {

        var defer = $q.defer();

        var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
        scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
        scriptTag.src = 'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';
        scriptTag.async = true;
        scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
                onScriptLoad();
            }
        }
        scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

        var script = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        script.appendChild(scriptTag);

        //---
        // PUBLIC API
        //---

        return {
            d3: function () {
                return defer.promise;
            }
        };

        //---
        // PRIVATE METHODS.
        //---

        // Load D3 in the browser
        function onScriptLoad () {
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                defer.resolve($window.d3);
            });
        }
    }]);
```

**Example 3: Using Compile adding SVG doesn't mean SVG is available in Link, but at least the compile's promise would always resolve first**

```
        // Perform DOM and template manipulations
        function compile ($element, $attrs, $transclude) {

            var svg;

            // Callback provides raw D3 object
            D3Service.d3().then(function (d3) {

                // Create a responsive SVG root element
                svg = d3.select($element[0])
                .append('svg')
                .style('width', '100%');
            });

            // Return the link function
            return function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

                // Is svg undefined? 

                // Maybe? so have to wrap everything again in service
                D3Service.d3().then(function (d3) {

                   function render() {
                       // d3 and svg guaranteed to be available, but code gets really ugly looking and untestable
                   }
                });

                function render() {
                    // d3 and svg have to be passed in as they may not be available, but code is cleaner
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: Yeah. Unless d3.js does something other than placing `d3` in the window scope, nothing is really more elegant than just a `$interval` promise for checking if it eventually exists. [on IE8, anyway]

Comment: Hi @Brian, so in the `link` of each graph directive wait on an a $interval promise and then use global reference of D3?  Seems like the solution could/should be DRYer, but maybe not...

Comment: I would implement "If d3 is undefined, then load d3 and wait, otherwise resolve immediately". If someone has a better solution for browsers including IE8, please @ me!

Comment: I'd either use a global or the 1st approach. I see only pain resulting from the approach of trying to inject it into the DOM. Why bother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar questions when confronted with the issue of `d3` and `Angular`. It seemed there were several ways to approach the problem; each were viable, but none felt smooth or natural. At its core, `d3` and `Angular` just appear to be two very distinct technologies, and they don't play well together out-of-the-box. Don't get me wrong, they work together fantastically, but they need to warm up to each other. So at best, we can give `d3` a playground within the `Angular` framework. And I believe this playground should be a `directive`.

But regarding the modular `d3Service` approach that returns a promise (per the loading of the `d3.js` file):

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', ['d3'])
  .directive('barChart', ['d3Service', function(d3Service) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        d3Service.d3().then(function(d3) {
          // d3 is the raw d3 object
        });
      }}
  }]);
```

While this was detailed very well in the [ngNewsletter](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html), it just seems overkill to use a service that writes `script` tags directly to the DOM, when it could just be included in `index.html` with all the other javascript files. I mean, we have a `directive` that we know uses this file, so why not just load it purposely? No need to jump through hoops it seems, just:

```
<script src="/js/third-party/d3js/d3.min.js"></script>
```

However, this approach promise does provide modularity - let's say we're building multiple applications and each needed `d3`, then yes, being able to very easily inject our `d3` module at the application level is great. But, you're always going to have to wait on that promise, even though we know it's going to resolve immediately after the initial load, you'll need to resolve it nonetheless. In any directive or controller that uses it. Always. Bummer.

So as I said, I opted to just include `d3.js` in my `index.html`, and as such I can just access it in my directives without needing to resolve a promise. Here's maybe a parallel: FWIW, I use JQuery promises over Angular promises, so what do I do when I need JQuery? Well, I just call it when I need it (`$.Deferred()`), my point being that invoking `d3` in a similar fashion just didn't seem that egregious to me.

And while I do make use of a `d3Service`, its more for helper functions than anything else. For instance, when I want to obtain an SVG on which to do work, why not just call a function that gives me a responsive SVG:

**Directive (link)**

```
var svg = d3Service.getResponsiveCanvas(scope.id, margin, height, width);
```

**Service**

```
app.service('d3Service', function() {

  return {
      getResponsiveCanvas: function(id, margin, height, width) {
        return d3.select('#' + id)
              .append('div')
              .classed('svg-container', true)
              .append('svg')
              .attr('id', 'svg-' + id)
              .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
              .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + (width + margin.left + margin.right) + ' ' + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
              .classed('svg-content-responsive', true)
              .append('g')
              .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');
      }
  }
});
```

I have similar functions for adding axes to an SVG. And this does have a code smell, but again, by its very nature with `d3` we're manipulating the DOM directly, so my experience is wherever we put this, its going to be ugly and not feeling very Angular-like, so you might as well craft some services that make your life easier.

Comment: Wow thanks, that's very helpful.  When adding it to index.html and access it in the directive do you ever run into issues where d3 is undefined?  Seems like you must need to add an init() method like @Brian suggested in the comments, which runs an $interval checking $window.d3 before loading each of the individual charts.  Appreciate the answer from both perspectives.

Comment: @mtpultz So by directly including `d3` in our HTML file, we're guaranteed it will be loaded and ready for use by the time Angular has initialized itself. As such I haven't run into d3 being undefined. Think of it this way, by just being included in our HTML, it's just another JS file to be loaded by the browser and served up to the JS engine. If you use underscore.js or jquery, or any other third-party JS library, it's the same flow. @Brian seems to be referencing the loading of the promise, which if not loaded resolved correctly could be undefined. But the approach I noted doesnt use promises

Comment: Okay, I always forget how scripts are loaded.  So this is based on them being loaded sequentially as long as you don't set them to be async.  Thanks :)